# iOS - Testing User Interface (Auto Layout / Layout Constraints)

Tags: unit-testing, user-interface, ios6, autolayout

I am looking for best practices, advice, and insight on how to test a user interface that leverages layout constraints.

My view controller subclass is displaying "leaf-level" data - for sake of example, let's say the app catalogs DVDs and this view controller is the `DiscDetailViewController` and you pass it a `DigitalDisc` instance which has five string properties. The goal is to display those strings in labels and to flow everything correctly with appropriate `NSLayoutConstraint`.

I would like to write a series of tests that exercise as many reasonable permutations of a `DigitalDisc` instance being passed into this view controller and make sure that I've defined sufficient constraints.

For example, I have a `DigitalDisc` instance, set it's `title` and `director` properties and lob it at the `DiscDetailViewController` ... Ack! What shall I assert? I'm stuck!

My motivation for testing is to ward off regression bugs. Auto layout (especially in IB) is fickle, but this doesn't seem to be exclusive to auto layout. I don't want to fix one bug only to cascade a bunch of new failures. Are these unit tests? Are they UIAutomation tests? Are they something else entirely?

**-----EDIT-----**

Let's say my `DigitalDisc` class is defined as follows:

```
@interface DigitalDisc : NSObject

@property NSString *title;
@property NSString *year;
@property NSString *director;
@property NSString *studio;
@property NSString *review;

@end
```

I'd like to check to make sure that my layout constraints are flexible enough to allow for a `DigitalDisc` instance that may not have values in ever field; the only requirement is the `title` field. This means that removing subviews should flow the interface correctly. What do I mean by "correctly?"

1. Without ambiguous and unsatisfiable constraints *(I can test a UIView for `-hasAmbigiousLayout` but how to test the exception that is thrown and caught?)*
2. That labels expand to multiple lines to avoid truncation
3. That adjacent labels are never closer nor further than standard distance
4. That the above are true in portrait and landscape

*(that's enough to get me down the rabbit hole so I can think about satisfying some of the other requirements)*

---

Here are some mocked screens that are sure to win the next ADA

**What a fully populated `DigitalDisc` instance would look like in the view controller**
[image: A fully filled in <code>DigitalDisc</code>]

**What a partially populated `DigitalDisc` instance might look like in the view controller.**

*Notice the "Year" label from the above screen shot has been removed and the "Director" label has moved up. This is the type of specification / behavior I've very interested in testing.*

[image: A <code>DigitalDisc</code> with only title and director]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding your problem, but the way you described it I would look into using a table view or a collection view instead. Say you use a collection view, the data source would know how many cells and which properties would need to be shown given a `DigitalDisc`. That's easily unit testable without launching an interface at all. Then, a custom collection view layout could ensure that each cell is the proper height (given text length in a label) and proper distance from other cells. This would also be unit testable.

Then you can just wire up your collection view data source and custom collection view layout and be done. Maybe do a couple UI Automation tests for sanity checks if need be. But I would try to push edge case testing like you describe down to lower level tests that don't touch the interface. The separation that Apple already encourages with collection view data sources and layouts sounds like a good way to break up your problem so you can thoroughly test it.

Yes, you could try to do what you want with autolayout, but you'd have to be calculating the height of the labels, anyway, and you'd be spinning up the UI every time which would be slow.

Comment: I've definitely taken this approach with "static" table views in the past, but was lead to believe that auto layout was a panacea for custom view layout in iOS 6. Assuming I go table/collection view route, does this not seem "a little wrong" since the nature of those views is to show homogenous data?

Comment: Don't worry, your "a little wrong" feeling is...well...wrong. :) The built-in contacts app is a great example of a heterogenous table view. The reason the data source and delegate can return any kind or size of cell is precisely because they wanted to allow for any mix and match of cell types you want. There's nothing wrong with this.

Comment: I took your advice and went two directions: #1 built an intermediate controller object that maps properties to index paths, and #2 used Fraser Spears enum technique with collection view. Option 1 has been more challenging (it's a juggling act, really), and works like NSFetchedResultsController (but KVO's properties instead of listening for MOC's notifications). Option 2 "just works" because a section with zero items doesn't display. Not sure which one I like more, but thought others might be interested in the approaches.

Comment: ...oh! and as for testing, both of these methodologies have allowed me to make simple `assert row count == ___` type unit tests and rely on collection view to lay things out properly. This definitely has been the big win.